# Equivalence between Hamiltonians of different dimensions

Tags: condensed-matter, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian, topology, topological-insulators

Consider a 2D lattice Hamiltonian $H_2$ of symmetry class A  and a 1D ladder Hamiltonian $H_1$ of class AIII having the same number of bands and the same TKNN number for each band.

Can $H_2$ and $H_1$ be homotopy equivalent in the usual sense of the existence of a smooth deformation between them that keeps open all gaps?
Usually I would think that the different symmetry classes imply this is impossible, however I know this to be true only within equal dimensions. For manifolds we know that equal dimension is a necessary condition for homotopy equivalence. But for the case of Hamiltonians, I don't see an obvious reason for why this should be the case.
If it is, does the same hold true for stable equivalence from K-theory?

If there is some equivalence notion in which it is possible, are the stated properties sufficient to conclude that they are equivalent?
From the work of [Avron, Seilinger, and Simon](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/85896/1/PhysRevLett.51.51.pdf) we know that two Bloch Hamiltonians are homotopy equivalent iff their TKNN numbers are equal. However this assumes that Hamiltonians are matrix valued functions on  Brioullin zones of equal dimensions.